# Postgresql archive (streaming replication) getting bigger. How to remove the archived xlog files?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am checking for a way to safely delete the **archived xlog** files(not the files under **pg_xlog** folder). I have postgresql streaming replication configured in my cluster. This is used by a fairly busy application and I have configured the "**archive_timeout**" variable to be 1 minute. I normally take a **pg_basebackup** overnight. Now, I need a way to safely delete the old archive files. Is there any recommended methods to do it?

Regards

Muhammed Roshan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to keep all WAL archives from the starting point of your oldest backup if you want to restore.

So the correct thing would be to tie WAL archive removal to the removal of base backups. When you remove an old base backup, delete all WAL archives up to the point in time when that backup was taken. That leaves you with a day's worth of unneeded WAL archives, but you are on the safe side.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I would like to know whether I can use "pg_archivecleanup" to clean up the archives. if yes, what is the correct method to do this.?

Comment: No, `pg_archivecleanup` is for use with streaming replication. It removes WAL archives no longer needed for the standby to catch up. It has no idea how long you keep your base backups around.